# Mouse position/control in Terminal, OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, mouse

On Windows, you can get the mouse position from an application running in the Terminal (or command prompt, as it's called there) by using `GetCursorPos()`, and even simulate mouse clicks and movements using `mouse_event()` and `SetCursorPos()` respectively. These functions can be found in `windows.h`.

I'm looking for the same functionality under Mac OS X in Terminal.app. Is this possible, and if so, can it be done without libraries? If not, is it possible in another terminal or not at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the `ncurses` library.  See this [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mousemask.3x.html).

Comment: From that manpage, I take it that you can only get the mouse status, not set it?

Comment: The last time I checked the `ncurses` mouse support didn't work in Terminal.app.

Comment: @tomsmeding Yeah I guess so.

Comment: @bdash Sounds like a bug - perhaps it's been fixed (I've never used it myself).

Comment: I think it's more a case of unimplemented functionality. There is a SIMBL plug-in that claims to add support to Terminal at https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/, and I suspect that it may work fine in alternative terminal clients such as iTerm2.

Comment: As a test, `getmouse()` seemed to be defined but when linking, gcc says: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_getmouse"`. Does anyone know what I have to link my program with, if anything? Or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @tomsmeding Yeah you'll need to add `ncurses` to the libraries to link against.

Comment: @trojanfoe Just found out that works out to `-lncurses` as a flag to `gcc`. Well I suppose it works :)